Trying to diagnose external hard drive malfunction
What's the issue with this Seagate external hard drive:

its activity light stays on after I issue the 'safely remove hardware' command on laptop 1 (before physically removing it from the laptop); this doesn't happen on laptop 2, once I click on 'safely remove hardware', its light goes off;
on both laptops, after connecting the drive, its light turns on, off, or blinks, even when not reading from or writing to it.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If Windows confirms it's safe to disconnect, nothing is wrong with the drive; ignore the light on it.
However, Windows "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media" is sometimes flaky and does not respond with the message that it is safe to remove the drive. If you'd like extra insurance the drive is safe to remove, try a third-party tool, such as Hotswap! or one of the many alternatives.
[On one Windows PC, I find the "Safe to Remove Hardware" notice fails to show about half the time after using the the built-in (Windows) Eject tool. Certainly, it would be nice if I could find the cause of that issue in Windows Eject, and fix it, but after many hours of fruitless effort, I've weaseled out and used Hotswap!.]
